# Akka Actor cleans its state unexpectedly

Tags: java, akka, actor

I have [this](https://github.com/Sergey80/akka-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/s2_example/actors/AggregateWordCountActor.java) actor that is involved in *parallel-word-count-calculation*.

It has a state:

```
private Map<String, Integer> wordCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

As it received `WordCountMapMessage` message, it changed the state to have `9 elements` in it:

```
{over=1, fell=1, fox=1, quick=1, tried=1, brown=1, lazy=1, dog=2, jump=1}
```

([there is](https://github.com/Sergey80/akka-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/s2_example/WordCountApp.java) `main class` for that - you can see outputs if you launch it)

Then when it receives `ResultMessage`, then  `wordCountMap` is empty.

**Q:** How come, all of the sudden it has empty map/state?

Is that possible that Actor is re-initializing its state somehow with no message passed?

--
**Update:**
If I ovveride methods `preStart` in `AggregateWordCountActor`, then I can see output like this:

> pre-start pre-start pre-start pre-start pre-start

It seems it starts 5 times ! But it does not launch any `preRestart`

Comment: This actor would initialize its state if it fails and is restarted by its supervisor. Is it possible that there is an uncaught exception being hit it your code resulting in a restart?  If you override preRestart and print something you can see if a restart is happening.

Comment: I did. preRestart is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that you are using a `RoundRobinPool` for each child actor in the `Master` actor.  Because your child actors are stateful, when the request comes in to request the current state, it goes to a different actor instance then the one that received the request to process the words (via the round robin routing logic).  Remove the routers from your child actor creation in the `Master` actor and your code should work.

Comment: Pretty much like ejb stateless beans and its pool.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems it starts 5 times ! But it does not launch any preRestart

That's because you are using `withRouter(new RoundRobinPool(5))` -- it creates 5 actors that will receive messages in round-robin fashion.

Problem is that you are receiving state of different actor than have completed computation: actors that will receive `WordCountMapMessage` and `ResultMessage` are not the same.